# Autodesk Forge Multiple OAuth2 Return URLs in an Application?

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have thee primary authentication environments, a dev, a production and long term support.

Currently we have three applications registered, one for each of our environments, only because it seems like we can only register one return URL per application.

Normally this wouldn't be a big deal, but we are also migrating from an old domain to a new one and would like to be able to keep all six (3 environments x 2 domains) return URLS active during the transition.

Google Auth and Box allow us to have multiple return url base addresses registered. Is there a way to do in in Forge?

Thanks.

Comment: Not doable at the moment, a Forge App can only support a single callback url ...

Comment: @Phllippe Thanks. If you want, post that as an answer I'll mark this answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close out this question, I'll take Phillipe's comment as the answer.

> Not doable at the moment, a Forge App can only support a single
>   callback url ... – Philippe Leefsma